# Can we have a ASP.NET Webservice on WordPress Site?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web-services, wordpress

I want to use ASP.NET webservice on a WordPress Site.

So, if the site is www.abc.com, can I access the service at www.abc.com/WS/serv.asmx?

If it is not possible to do so, what can be a workaround for this, as I MUST use that asp.net webservice at all cost.

Please guide me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running IIS with both PHP and ASP.NET installed, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to run both within the same site.