# Is it Possible to upload a ASP.Net WebService into WordPress Site?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, wordpress, web-services

This question was answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235871/can-we-have-a-asp-net-webservice-on-wordpress-site) but there is no explanation on how they did it? Is there any step by step method on how can I upload a webservice into wordpress site?

Comment: Is your website running on IIS with ASP.NET installed?

Comment: How would I know if it's running in IIS?

Comment: It's your site running on the server you either installed or subscribe to.  Check with the people who offer or installed the service for you.  Although not rare, it is uncommon to have both.

Comment: So without IIS then there is no possibility to upload it in wordpress site?

Comment: What you really want to do is a bit unclear.  There are always ways to replicate what would be done in the APS.NET script into a PHP script, but you'd obviously need to know all the specs in detail or be fluent in both languages.

Comment: I have a desktop application(C# windows form) used for login into a PHP website. Basically I created an ASP.NET webservice to connect mysql database into my C# windows form.

Comment: Then you do have both installed.  Your main difficulty might be to integrate it to WordPress but changing anything in it can be a huge question by itself.

Comment: If your server has been installed .net, then you will be able to use ASP.NET. But, as I know you cant integrate asp.net to your wordpress site as wordpress use php.

Answer (score 1):

Is it Possible to upload a ASP.Net WebService

---

Yes It is possible `WebService` can be hosted. your question should be how can we do that rather than this. 
A simple answer to that is contact your `Host`.
One needs an `IIS` server to host stuff that is build in `.NET Framework` specifically if that is a `WebService` `API` or any thing that requires `HTTP` `Protocol`.

After Hosting a `webservice` your question will/Should be how to access it, that is a totally different question and you can find help related to that 
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524228/REST-tutorial-Call-a-REST-Webservice-from-Wordpres) and [Here](https://blogsandip.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/calling-aspnet-web-service-from-php/)

I hope this helps you in any way and don't worry about vote down you'll  get used to